# How to store images in Laravel 10?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-10

I am trying to make a function that stores name, slug, description, image, and metadata with Laravel for my project.

Here's the store function in my CategoryController.php file.

```
public function store(CategoryFormRequest $request)
{
    $validatedData = $request->validated();

    $category = new Category([
        'name' => $validatedData['name'],
        'description' => $validatedData['description'],
        'meta_title' => $validatedData['meta_title'],
        'meta_keyword' => $validatedData['meta_keyword'],
        'meta_description' => $validatedData['meta_description'],
    ]);

    $category->slug = SlugService::createSlug(Category::class, 
        'slug', $validatedData['name']);

    if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
        $file = $request->file('image');
        $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $filename = time().'.'.$extension;
        $path = $file->storeAs('uploads/category', $filename);
        $category->image = $path;
    }

    $category->status = $request->status == true ? '1' : '0';
    $category->save();

    return redirect('admin/category/')
        ->with('message', 'Successfully added a category!');
}
```

Everything that is text related is being saved and stored successfully except the storing image into the path specified, although in the database, it says that there is a file being saved. For example, if an image is being saved on the image column, it specifies the path as "uploads/category/1676976218.png". As per the path itself, I have it saved in the public folder

Comment: What isn't working? Is the file not stored at all, or in the wrong directory?

Comment: `php artisan storage:link`?

Answer (score 1):

First run the following command

```
php artisan storage:link
```

Then try to upload the file again. Your image path will be.

```
storage/app/uploads/category/1676976218.png
```

If `storeAs` does not work then just use the following code

```
$imageName = time().'.'.$request->image->extension();  
   
$request->image->move(public_path('images'), $imageName);
```